# Java scanner not recognizing filename?

Tags: java, parsing

I am writing a parser that removes all punctuation from a text file and puts the words in a Map that associates each word with the number of times it occurs in the file. I use a Scanner to read the txt file, but it reads the file name instead of the actual file. For instance:

```
    parse("./src/filename.txt")
```

is read as "srcfilenametxt" and is associated with a value 1. Unfortunately, I can't include more code because this is for a class assignment. How do I get it to correctly read the file?

Comment: `Scanner` does not have a `parse()` method. You'll need to show us at least a bit more code. Where is a `Scanner` involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Scanner` is constructed with a string parameter it scans the string, not the file named by the string. You'd need a line like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("./src/filename.txt"));
```

Comment: @AlexHaldeman: Glad to help. If you would like to tick this answer as having met your needs, that will save other people coming to your question and suggesting other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use bufferedreader to read a file

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));
```